# Test Control Handle under Mobile .Net CF

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

When my threads complete, I keep getting exceptions thrown.

I can catch them, but I'd rather my code catch them first.

This code could work for the full .Net Framework, but `IsHandleCreated` doesn't exist under the *Compact Framework*.

**Question:** *What should I use instead of `IsHandleCreated`?*

```
Control _parent; // set when custom BackgroundWorker like class is created

bool parentOk {
  get {
    if (_parent != null) {
      if (!_parent.IsDisposed) {
        return _parent.IsHandleCreated;
        // Should I instead "return (_parent.Handle != IntPtr.Zero);"?
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

public void ReportProgress(int step, object data) {
  lock (_thLock) {
    if (parentOk && (ProgressChanged != null)) {
      MethodInvoker methInvoker = delegate { ProgressChanged(step, data); };
      try {
        _parent.BeginInvoke(methInvoker); // recently changed from below
        // _parent.Invoke(methInvoker); (old technique)
      } catch (ObjectDisposedException) { // added for BeginInvoke
      } catch (NullReferenceException err) {
        Global.LogError(_CODEFILE + "ReportProgress", err);
      } catch (InvalidOperationException err) {
        Global.LogError(_CODEFILE + "ReportProgress", err);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, are you seeing?  is it that `IsDisposed` is false, but trying to Invoke on the parent still fails?

Comment: It happens too fast. By the time my debugger gets it, it doesn't exist. The actual error message I get is `Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting (and not well documented that I've ever found) is that an Control's Handle isn't actually created until it is queried.  It seems that in ost cases that happens internally to the framework just fine, but in cases where you are using a control for Invoking, there are occasions where it hasn't happened and you get an `Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created` Exception.

My solution has always been to query the handle directly early on.  In your case you can probably get away with something like this (like your comment suggests):

```
bool ParentOk
{
    get
    {
        return (_parent != null)
            && (!_parent.IsDisposed)
            && (_parent.Handle != IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'll test this and be in touch!

Comment: Yeah, this bit me for a long time with my "UIThread" event aggregation in my IoC framework.  Took me forever to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in .NET Compact Framework 2.0 is it not possible to check for create, because the Handle is direct in base class created, so when you call `new Control()` it has already a handle created. So the only way I found to check whether handle is still valid is to access the `Handle` property.

If this throws an ObjectDisposedException, then you know it has no valid handle.
If no exception occur handle is still valid.

The `IsDisposed` property is not existing in .NET Compact Framework 2.0, so no idea what the previous answer is about.